# convert a simple code from javaScript to asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to convert this simple code that shows a multiplication table from java script ( using notepad++) to asp.net ( using visual studio// web form )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="windows-1252">
        </head>
        <body>
            <script> 
    document.write("<table border=\"1px\">");
    var i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      document.write("<tr><th colspan=\"5\">Table" + " " + i + "</th></tr>");
      for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
        document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>"+"<td>*</td>"+"<td>" + j + "</td>"+"<td>=</td>"+"<td>" + i * j + "</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
      </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: instead of document.write you can concatenate the html in stringbuilder class object and return it.

Comment: As it stands, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Here, you post your code, the expected output and the issue. This would better be done by taking an ASP.NET tutorial, and a javascript tutorial, then using the corresponding statements/functions of the target language. If you get stuck, come back and we will be glad to help.